# using start /wait for a headless process in a batch file - any way to show the process is running?

Tags: command-line-interface, batch-file, windows-command-prompt, batch

So I have a large batch file, and in the middle it hits a start /wait command to run a silent install of an MSI. I'd like to have some animation or something to indicate that the batch file is in fact doing something, as it can take some minutes. Is there any way to fire off the start /wait command but still keep some looping code in the batch file to run an animation that can show it is working on something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599427/wait-for-wmic-to-finish-remote-call